# How to add value to a variable of type Other>double[] in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to calculate the 90th percentile value of a data. In order to so, I have created a variable of type Other> double[].

And I am trying to populate the list using variable.add(time()-agent.downEndTime);
But this is not working. The error returned is
[image]

Once I am able to do so, I plan to sort the list in ascending order, and calculate the 90th percentile value based on the size of the list.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an arraylist instead of an array... use a collections object from the agent palette of type ArrayList with element type double.

Then you can do the downwardtime.add();

then to sort, depending on whether you want ascending or descending:

```
Collections.sort(downwardtime);
```

or

```
Collections.sort(downwardtime, Collections.reverseOrder());
```